# Coordinate transformation results are different between Proj4JS and pyproj

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, epsg, proj4js

I try to make a coordinate converter using Proj4JS for mobile app, I use [this](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/proj4js) source code. Before I tested conversion for WGS84 geographic and WGS84 UTM, there was not problem with it. I tested conversion from [TUREF TM zone:27](https://epsg.io/5253) to [ED50 TM zone:27](https://epsg.io/2319) that input coordinates are Easting:507768.06 Northing:4354677.64. For proj4js output is; Easting:507819.315 Northing:4354847.596 But when I tested it for [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=5253&t_srs=2319&x=507768.0600000&y=4354677.6400000) or pyproj output was Easting:507815.93 Northing:4354857.26.

Edit: I use proj4 text parameters for pyproj and proj4js.

```
TUREF / TM27: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=27 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
ED50 / TM27: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=27 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I used proj4.js file. After replacing it with [proj4-src.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/proj4js) it transforms properly right now. I will continue testing.